# Searching for a JQuery plugin that allow to show pictures after scroll down on a page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am searching for a JQuery plugin, which allows me to load a picture on a page only if it is in the visual field of a visitor. For example I go to a site then, all the pictures which I see are shown, now i scroll down and the new pictures will loaded automatically now (this plugin should provide the browser to load all the images on a site from the start)

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this could help http://plugins.jquery.com/project/lazyload